# Joining dataframes with indices

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have `df=[4,5,6]` and `df2=[7,8,9]`, for both indices are `0,1,2`.

I used `pd.concat([df,df1])`, but the result gives me indices `0,1,2,0,1,2`.

I want resulting df indices `0,1,2,3,4,5`

Any help ?

Comment: I'm not familar with pandas but in python concatenating lists is possible with `df+df2`.

Answer (score 5):

```
pd.concat([df,df2], ignore_index=True )
```

[image]